# Check if value is being used as a filter (Power Bi)

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I'm using a column as a Power BI binary filter. The data frame is like:

```
+---------+-------+
| Measure | Value |
+---------+-------+
| Growth  |   $   |
| Profit  |   %   |
| Profit  |   $   |
+---------+-------+
```

I expect that when I select $ on visual my calculated column bring this:

```
+---------+-------+----------+
| Measure | Value | Selected |
+---------+-------+----------+
| Growth  |   $   |        1 |
| Profit  |   %   |        0 |
| Profit  |   $   |        1 |
+---------+-------+----------+
```

Where 1 means that $ was selected by user.

Any ideas on how to generate dax capable of classifying whether the value was selected or not in the visual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something along the lines of

```
Selected = IF ( SELECTEDVALUE ( TableName[Value] ) = "$", 1, 0 )
```

The DAX functions [ISFILTERED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/isfiltered-function-dax) and [HASONEVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/hasonevalue-function-dax) may be of interest too.